# Calculate YTD and Prior YTD for any given month using SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to build a chart that shows revenue for current YTD and prior YTD for any given month I have data for, generated via SQL that can be retrieved into a report from a view at any time.

The table would look something like this

```
USER1 | MONTH | YEAR | REVENUE | YTD REVENUE | PRIOR YTD REVENUE |
------------------------------------------------------------------
Dan   | Feb   | 2016 |  $75    |   $75       |                   
Bob   | Feb   | 2016 |         |             |                   
Chris | Feb   | 2016 |  $220   |   $220      |     
Dan   | Jan   | 2017 |  $100   |   $100      |     
Bob   | Jan   | 2017 |  $150   |   $150      |     
Chris | Jan   | 2017 |  $200   |   $200      |     
Dan   | Feb   | 2017 |  $100   |   $200      |     $75
Bob   | Feb   | 2017 |  $100   |   $250      |     
Chris | Feb   | 2017 |  $125   |   $225      |     $220
```

How could I calculate Current YTD and prior YTD via sql by month as part of building said view? I am currently not calculating YTD by month / year per the example above, so would need to include that in the statement along with calculating PYTD as well.

Currently the SQL query is

```
Select USER1, MONTH(Date), YEAR(Date), REVENUE from SOURCE
```

Comment: Would prior be just the previous month (e.g. `LAG() OVER()`) or the total (e.g. `SUM() OVER()`)?

Comment: Why Chris - Feb - 2017 YTD REVENUE is 225 ?

Answer (score 2):

You would use window functions.  This is going to assume that "month" is really a month-number column.  That makes more sense than just a month:

```
select t.*,
       lag(ytd) over (partition by user1, month order by year) as prev_ytd
from (select t.*,
             sum(revenue) over (partition by user1, year order by month) as ytd
      from t
     ) t;
```

This assumes that all users have data for every month in question.

EDIT:

If you are missing rows:

```
with tc as (
      select t.*,
             sum(revenue) over (partition by user1, year order by month) as ytd
      from t
     )
select tc.*, tcprev.ytd
from tc outer apply
     (select top (1) tcprev.ytd
      from tc tcprev
      where tcprev.user1 = tc.user1 and
            tcprev.year = tc.year and
            tcprev.month <= tc.month
      order by tcprev desc
     ) tcprev;
```

Comment: What happens in this case if they don’t? There will be those months where that’s the case

Comment: @Danimov82 . . . Then somewhat more complicated code is needed.  Your sample data has complete data for all names for all months, so it seems like a reasonable assumption.

Comment: Yes, the sample data does have complete columns but the actual data does not. I can revise the sample, thank you

Comment: Getting an "invalid column name" for tcprev though not seeing where the error lies. The table itself is t (or in my case, SalesActivity) so fine there but not clear why I'm getting that error for your formula above.

Comment: Also in running select t.*,
             
sum(revenue) over (partition by user1, year order by month) as ytd
      from t

The amount that comes out is the same as the amount in the given column for the month / year vs a cumulative YTD